# Posting to Spotify API for tokens is returning status 415. Am I missing something?

Tags: json, swift, httprequest, spotify

Here is my method for hitting their API for their Authorization Code Flow:

```
class func obtainAuthTokenPackage(authCode: String) throws
{
    //Create a request
    var request = URLRequest(url: Gimme.theSpotify.urlFor(endpoint: .requestingTokens)) //"https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    //Build the header
    let spotifyClientCreds = Gimme.theSpotify.clientID + ":" + Gimme.theSpotify.clientSecret
    let encodedCreds = spotifyClientCreds.data(using: .utf8)!.base64EncodedString()
    request.setValue("Basic \(encodedCreds)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    //Build the body
    var dict = [String:String]()
    dict["grant_type"] = "authorization_code"
    dict["code"] = authCode
    dict["redirect_uri"] = Gimme.theSpotify.redirectURI
    var package = Data()
    do
    {
        package = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict)
    }
    catch 
    {print("oopsie")}
    request.httpBody = package

    //Set up a web transaction
    let transaction = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
        (possData, possResp, possErr) in
        if let data = possData
        {
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
        }
    }
    //Do it
    transaction.resume()
}
```

The print statement near the bottom produces `{"error":"server_error","error_description":"Unexpected status: 415"}`

Things I've Tried Already:

- Changing `request.setValue(...` to `request.addValue(...` and vice versa doesn't seem to make a difference.
- Using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, changing the http body to `"grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + authCode + ...".data(using: .utf8)`.
  When I did this, API responds with a message that I need to set the grant type to authorization_code (which tells me their server isn't parsing my http body correctly).
- Moving client credentials from the header to the body (using JSON).
- Creating my http body using Swift 4's new JSON encoding tools
- Requesting using the Rested app (it's like Postman or HTTPRequestor)
- Implementing their Implicit Grant Flow *with success*. But that doesn't give a refresh token and I need it :(.
- Sobbing internally so I don't distract people around me
- Changing `Content-Type` to `content-type`
- Removing the header field that specifies content type
- Escaping characters in the `redirect-uri` (e.g. replacing colons with %3A, slashes with %2F)

Questions I Have:

- Status 415 means unsupported media type, so is the Spotify API expecting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of JSON?
- If you can get Spotify's Authorization Code Flow working in your Swift project, what did you do different?
- If you use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, how did you create your http body?

I appreciate any help, thanx guys.

Comment: Have you tried not encoding the credentials in the header?

Comment: Oh, yes I have. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's expecting a JSON request body. Give the [code flow](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization_code_flow) part of the guide a read, and try the whole thing with `curl` as a sanity check, but your code looks right.

Comment: And play with the content types. Maybe even leave it off. Even try lower-case "content-type" for the header name.

Comment: I figured it out. Check out my answer. Thank you for the time you took to review my problem, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I DID IT! HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA!!!!!!!!!!!

```
//The endpoint expects form-urlencoded
request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

//Build a string that has client_id, client_secret, grant_type, the code, and the redirect uri
//It has to be in that order (I didn't try any other order, but I've been having this problem for so long, I don't want to risk anything)
//It has to be in the form "key=value&key=value..." (Standard form url encoded format)
var formEncoded = "client_id=\(Gimme.theSpotify.clientID)"
formEncoded.append("&client_secret=\(Gimme.theSpotify.clientSecret)")
formEncoded.append("&grant_type=authorization_code")
formEncoded.append("&code=\(authCode)")
formEncoded.append("&redirect_uri=\(Gimme.theSpotify.redirectURI)")

//Finally convert it into UTF8 data
let bodyData = formEncoded.data(using: .utf8) //Check that this isn't nil, then proceed

//Stick this stuff in the transaction, and it'll be SUCCESSFULLLLL
```

Questions I had that I am able to answer now:
 - This api endpoint https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as the Content-Type.
 - What I did different: I included client ID and client secret before the `grant_type` key in the body instead of putting it in the header
 - I created my http body manually as demonstrated by the code segment above.

In conclusion:
 - Nothing really fancy needed
 - Spotify API documentation is lacking (but c'mon, who's isn't?)
 - I'm relieved